# Unable to fetch data from product list page to product details page in flutter using JSON API

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, e-commerce

I'm trying to fetch the data from product list to product details page using json API. I'm using grid tile for product list.

```
          var data = json.decode(response.body) as List;
          print(data);
          List<Product> temp = [];
          data.forEach((element) {
            Product product = Product.fromJson(element);
            temp.add(product);
          });
          _products = temp;
          return true;
        } catch (e) {
          print("e getProducts");
          print(e);
          return false;
        }
      }
    
      List<Product> get products {
        return [..._products];
      }
    
      Product singleProduct(int id) {
        return _products.firstWhere((element) => element.barCode == id);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your json response and what error occurs?

Comment: What's the actual error you get?